# WPF DataGridRow Events - "Selected" event inheritance

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, events, datagrid

I have this piece of code in my program:

```
        <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <EventSetter Event="Selected" Handler="Selection_event"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I can't find where is `Selected` event is inherited from.

[DataGridRow Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridrow_events%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

[UIElement Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement_events%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

I am looking for something like `Unselected` and want to see what are the events near `Selected`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I can't find where is Selected event is inherited from.**

The `Selected` `Event` occurs when the `IsSelected` property of the `DataGridRow` is `true`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridrow.selected.aspx)

**I am looking for something like Unselected and want to see what are the events near Selected**

For a complete list of DataGridRow Events, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridrow.aspx). The one you are looking for is the `UnSelected` [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridrow.unselected.aspx), which occurs when the row selection is cleared.